# bash shell or awk script for data organization

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two column data like this:

```
*x y  
0 -3.9  
0.14 -4.32  
0.14 -4.5  
0.23 -3.95  
0.23 -3.8  
0.5 -4.1  
0.7 -4.3  
...  
1.0 -4.5*
```

As you see some x values are the same.
I want to choose the lowest y-value in case of same x-values.
So, the above data will be reduced like this:

```
x y  
0 -3.9  
0.14 -4.5  
0.23 -3.95  
0.5 -4.1  
0.7 -4.3  
...  
1.0 -4.5
```

Is anybody to know how to make it by simple script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you actually tried any tools like awk or python?  Just dumping a problem here is less likely to get help than if you actually try and solve it yourself, and come here, show the code you have so far, and then get help on parts you're having trouble with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer for what I want:

```
sort -k1,1n -k2,2g file | awk '!a[$1] {a[$1] = $2} $2 == a[$1]'
```

Answer (score 1):

No script required if you have datamash.  `sudo apt install datamash` on debian-based (Ubuntu) systems.  pacman and other "default" package manager repos tend to have this as an available package as well.

```
Khazad-dum:~/test£ cat thingy
0 -3.9
0.14 -4.32
0.14 -4.5
0.23 -3.95
0.23 -3.8
0.5 -4.1
0.7 -4.3
```

Tell datamash to columnize by whitespace, group by column 1, and print the minimum value of column 2:

```
Khazad-dum:~/test£ datamash -W -g 1 min 2 <thingy
0       -3.9
0.14    -4.5
0.23    -3.95
0.5     -4.1
0.7     -4.3
```

The following awk will work, until column 2 contains positive values.  You'd want to modify the if statement to check for the existence of the key if that's the case.  Exercise for the reader:  "how to tell if awk associative array contains key" (`c1` is associative array...column 1/`$1` is key)

```
awk '{if (c1[$1] > $2) {c1[$1] = $2}} END {for (key in c1) {print key "  " c1[key]}}' thingy
```